# How to manage customized names of excel cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, address-bar, naming

In order to [create hyperlinks within an excel sheet](https://www.excel-university.com/link-to-sheets-using-defined-names/), I've to give the target cell a custom name, which will change its default name (i.e. B12) to the new name I defined (i.e. B12 = Anchor1). So, when I right click on the target cell, and choose "define name" from the context menu, I even may add a **short description** for this custom name.
If I go to a different cell from where I want to create the hyperlink, I get an overview of my custom names.

But how can I see this overview of custom names without the need to create or edit a hyperlink? I am asking, because I **want to see and change my description texts** for my custom cell names.

Comment: You can only open the Name Manager to change the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas ribbon > Defined Names > Name Manager or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> brings up the "Name Manager" dialog box, which lists all defined names with their descriptions.

Also useful: Formulas ribbon > Defined Names > Use in formula > Paste Names... or <kbd>F3</kbd> brings up the "Paste Names" dialog box, which lists all defined names (no description) but names can be easily inserted into formulae.